# Use regular expressions to match any number of characters as long as the first character isn't a digit

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying figure out how to use regular expressions to match any number of characters as long as the first character isn't a number. I also want it to match if there are no values in the portion of the string I'm checking (the end of it).

If I do this:

```
Pattern = re.compile (value + r"\D.*")
```

It only works if the string has at least one (non-digit) value after the match value.

If I do this:

```
Pattern = re.compile (value + r"\D?.*")
```

It will match even if the first value is a digit.

I'm trying to find a match for zero to any values at the end of the string, as long as the first value isn't a digit.

Examples:

> Check "abc123" against:
>
> "abc123" : Match
> "abc123ab" : Match
> "abc1234" : Not a match
> "abc1234a" : Not a match
> "abc123a4" : Match

Comment: What do you mean by "I also want it to match if there are no values in the portion of the string I'm checking (the end of it)?"

Comment: can you put some sample code and expected output?

Comment: Is `value` supposed to be part of the regular expression, or what is matched *against* the regular expression?

Comment: I've added examples that should help explain what I'm looking for. Let me know if you it still needs clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a *"negative lookahead assertion"* (search that term [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html)).

```
re.compile(value + '(?!\d)')
```

That literally means "not (directly) followed by a digit".

---

*Alternatively*, without regular expressions (basic idea taken from TigerhawkT3):

```
not teststring[len(value):][:1].isdigit()
```

This assumes that the test string starts with the value (if that's not guaranteed, you'd have to check it).

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
def check(string, value):
    return not string[len(value)].isdigit() if len(value)<len(string) else True
```

Results:

```
check('abc123', 'abc123')
True
check('abc123ab', 'abc123')
True
check('abc1234', 'abc123')
False
check('abc1234a', 'abc123')
False
check('abc123a4', 'abc123')
True
```

Comment: No problem - I like the use of slicing to avoid `IndexError`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an alternative between `\D` and the end of the string:

```
re.compile (value + r"(?:\D|$)")
```

Or this if you need to match until the end of the string:

```
re.compile (value + r"(?:\D.*|$)")
```

This will match the first digit or the end of the string.

It would also work with a lookahead if you don't need the whole string to be matched, only if you need to check if it's a match or not:

```
re.compile (value + r"(?=\D|$)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following .. just added a `?` (zero or one match) for your entire pattern than just `\D`:

```
Pattern = re.compile (value + r"(\D.*)?$")
```